# What does Adobe CryptoSupport use for hashing?

Tags: java, encryption, adobe, aem

I've read about the Adobe CryptoSupport that is now in CQ5.5+, which is meant to provide a utility for encrypting and decrypting data, for example, to store API keys in the JCR more securely.

The [JavaDocs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/crypto/CryptoSupport.html#NAME) or the general Adobe documentation give no details on its implementation, just stating that:

> Note that this method and the `decrypt(byte[])` method provide full
>   round trip support:
>
> ```
> decrypt(encrypt(plainText)).equals(plainText) == true
> ```
>
> Please note,
>   that calling this method twice on the same `plainText` does not return
>   the same cipher text:
>
> ```
> encrypt(plainText).equals(encrypt(plainText)) == false
> ```

This is reasonably useful, but what it doesn't tell me is how these ciphers are enncrypted to begin with. I've tried encrypting on one CQ instance & decrypting on another, but this doesn't seem to work.

To use this feature with confidence, I'd like to know on what CQ bases its encrypted.
There are two main concerns I have:

- How do I know that the service is salted (think that's the correct term) based on something secure? Or if it needs to be configured, how do I do that? (i.e. does it use the equivalent level of security OOTB as a log-in of 'admin/admin'!)
- If the encryption is environment specific, does this mean that I cannot encrypt data & then transfer across between servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle description in the Felix console states that

> The Crypto Support bundle provides a CryptoSupport services which
>   allows applications to encrypt and decrypt binary and String data.
>   Encryption is based on the symmetric AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (AES
>   algorithm, CBC mode with PKCS5 padding) from the RSA JSafe libary.

Key is randomly generated during the first start of the *Adobe Granite Crypto Support* bundle and then saved as `/etc/key/master` property. <strike>It is per-instance by design and I don't think it's a good idea to move this key between CQ installations.</strike> Actually, Adobe [says it's a good idea](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/wcm/campaigns/newsletters.html#Exporting%20keys%20from%20author%20and%20importing%20on%20publish) to move key between author and publish instances.

Answering your questions:

- you don't need to worry about configuring the service as it's done automatically during the first bundle activation,
- you can move encrypted data from one instance to another as long as you also move the key.

Comment: Ah cool, so it should be possible to configure multiple instances to use the same key so, I presume. I don't suppose you found a link to any documentation on that by any chance? :)

Comment: Yep, go ahead :) Unfortunately, no documentation.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to look for documentation under the "E-mail Marketing" pages! ;) Thanks & good spot on finding the Adobe recommended way too.

Comment: I've googled for the key path and this page came out first ;)